# how do i turn usb debuging on from fastboot?

Tags: usb-debugging

My touch doesn't work and I accidentally reset my phone from recovery.Now I am stuck on the phone setup phase and cant get anywhere.I am trying to mirror the phone's screen into a pc but says it needs usb debuging enabled in phone.

Answer (score 0):

> If the device supports USB host mode you can connect a **USB-OTG** (USB on the go) cable and connect a USB mouse or a USB keyboard to bypass the broken touchscreen. Then you can navigate to developers options to turn the usb debugging on.
>
> Find out more at : [How to turn on USB debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707137/how-to-find-and-turn-on-usb-debugging-mode-on-nexus-4)

Also have a look :[XDA Developers: Remotely turn on USB debugging](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/help/fastboot-recovery-remotely-enable-usb-t2177440) which explains different workaround but it need touchscreen to work.